# ¿Como guardar un Dataframe Creado en formato .CSV (python-pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

**Lo que tengo:**

Estoy trabajando un Archivo con extensión xlsx en un cuaderno de Jupyter y este archivo lo convertí a tipo Dataframe para tratar sus datos.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('archivo.xlsx')
df.head()
```

luego realice un tratamiento de los datos que implica la creación de nuevas columnas (en base a operaciones realizadas en otras columnas) que quiero guardar y después compruebo los datos tratados asi como las columnas resultantes. El Dataframe me aparece tratado con las columnas nuevas (por ejemplo existe una columna llamada 'MONTO PAGO'de la cual creo otra columna que se llama 'Pago efectivo' en la cual se guardan como 0 los datos de monto pago que son iguales o menores a 0 y como 1 si son mayores a 0), efectivamente cuando consulto con df.head() me muestra la columna añadida al dataset inicial.

**Lo que necesito**

Quiero guardar el Dataframe tratado en un archivo con extensión .csv

**Intenté con esto**

```py
df.to_csv('ARCHIVOTRATADO.csv')
```

**y esto**

```py
df.to_csv('ARCHIVOTRATADO.csv', header = False, index = False)
```

**Pero:**

El archivo nuevo que se guarda mantiene los datos originales sin el tratamiento realizado ni las nueva columnas, agradecería mucho a quién me pueda ayudar.

Comment: La forma de exportar a CSV es la correcta. Seguro el problema es que el dataframe al que le haces to_csv no tiene los cambios por algun motivo. Antes de llamar al metodo to_csv checkea que el df contiene los cambios que requieres.

Comment: Los contiene :C

Comment: Lo que comentas es muy raro, por favor podrías copiar todo el código para que veamos donde puede estar el problema?

Comment: Confirma que el dataframe exportado sea el que tiene la información modificada y recuerda visualizar el csv con un editor simple (nano, vi, notepad, notepad++) en vez de excel

Comment: `writer = ExcelWriter('archivotratado.xlsx')`

`df.to_excel(writer,'Hoja1')`

`writer.save()` intenta guardarlo en `.xlsx` recuerda  `from pandas import ExcelWriter` . De esta manera debería funcionar

Comment: Una idea más ¿no será que el `.csv` que estás guardando desde pandas va a parar a una carpeta diferente de la que imaginas, y el `.csv` que después examinas es otro que no ha cambiado nunca? Podrías forzar a guardar el `.csv` en una carpeta concreta especificando su ruta absoluta, por si acaso.

Comment: La información que entregas es insuficiente para replicar el problema. De hecho, funciona el método que mencionar por lo que el error o problema debe estar en otra parte del código. Procura mejorar tu pregunta incluyendo más información, tanto para replicar el error, pero más importante, lo que sea para lograr entender el problema a cabalidad.

Comment: Me encantaría entregar más información pero estoy tratando datos personales sobre deuda. Y no es posible que el error esté en otra parte del código porque cuando consulto el DataFrame aparece tratado, aparecen sus nuevas columnas con los datos tratados, sólo que en vez de guarda el dataframe tratado, me guarda el dataframe inicial con los mismos datos que están en el excel.

Comment: dices "cuando consulto el df" ¿puedes especificar como haces esa consulta? ¿estas usando jupyter? ¿puedes justo despues de la consulta y sin ninguna linea ni indentación adicional poner dfconsulta.to_csv('prueba.csv') y ver si te genera el archivo modificado?

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que estés haciendo los cambios en el dataframe, pero no lo reasignes. Es decir, no haces algo similar a esto:

```
df2 = df.assign(columnanueva = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'])
```

Todo esto, suponiendo que la creación de las nuevas columnas las hagas con *assign*